# JavaScript function return Object as JSON

Tags: javascript

In need to add an Object to my Firestore database. It only takes JSON objects. However I also want to exclude some fields of my object to not get send to my database.

So I added a function that should return a JSON like this:

```
export class Entry {

date: number;
timeStart: number;
timeEnd: number;
entry: EntryData;

// To be excluded from database
selected: boolean;

constructor(date: number, timeStart: number, timeEnd: number, entry: EntryData) {
    this.date = date;
    this.timeStart = timeStart;
    this.timeEnd = timeEnd;
    this.entry = entry;
}

toJSON() {
    return {date: this.date, timeStart: this.timeStart, timeEnd: this.timeEnd, entry: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.entry)) };
}
}
```

However when I do `console.log(entry.toJSON())` I get this:

```
workday.service.ts:122 ƒ () {
        return { date: this.date, timeStart: this.timeStart, timeEnd: this.timeEnd, entry: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.entry)) };
    }
```

I want to use the function like this:

```
this.employeeRef.collection('Entries').add(entry.toJSON);
```

But that doesn't work. It works like this:

```
    this.employeeRef.collection('Entries').add(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entry)));
```

But this way the `selected` field is not excluded from the database.

Any Ideas? Note that I'm using TypeScript (with Angular) but I think thats a pure JavaScript problem.

Comment: Your `toJSON` function returns an object. You *really* need to learn the difference between JSON and JavaScript objects so that you can ask a clear question.

Comment: I guess you actually did `console.log(entry.toJSON)` instead of `console.log(entry.toJSON())`

Comment: @JonasWilms damn your right, that was actually my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [getter:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Browser_compatibility)

```
 get toJSON() {
   return {date: this.date, timeStart: this.timeStart, timeEnd: this.timeEnd, entry: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.entry)) };
 }
```

Comment: You may want to include some documentation (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Browser_compatibility) with this answer. A nooby javascript user may not know what a getter is

Comment: Damn now I feel stupid, I forgot the () as you mentioned. Also I had to change the method a little bit, I awserded below

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
toJSON() {
    return {date: this.date, timeStart: this.timeStart, timeEnd: this.timeEnd, entry: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.entry)) };
}
```

I can use it like this:

```
his.employeeRef.collection('Entries').add(entry.toJSON());
```